# CSS Positioning with z-index and absolute

Tags: css, positioning

I have this test URL: http://effectwave.com/test/responsive/viewport/index-test.htm
I am trying that the Content section (Blue Area) should go over the Footer area. The place where it says 'Footer Content' should then get pushed down accordingly.

I know that this can be achieved by z-index and absolute positioning. I have tried it to no avail and I am not an expert to pull it off. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following do what you want?

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
footer {
    margin-top: -430px;
}
.footer-content {
    padding-top: 440px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it did help. This is a good starting point. I can play with the numbers and get my desired result. But since I am new to this could you please explain what exactly happens here, so that I can use that knowledge for future applications?

Comment: The `z-index:10` and `position:relative` ensures the wrapper is placed on top of other things, but without moving the other things nothing changes. The negative `margin-top` moves the footer up, so that it comes to lie under the wrapper; but this also means its text now lies under the wrapper. The `padding-top` creates extra empty space at the top so that we push the text of the footer down where its visible again.